# Why isn't this button being selected by jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events

I'm running angular, bootstrap, jQuery setup, for some reason I can't seem to have jQuery select this button, it does nothing when clicking it:

```
$('#some_button').click(function(e) { 
      alert('testing');
});

<button id="some_button">some button</button>
```

As simple as it looks, for some reason it's not popping up the alert message...

**EDIT**
Sorry, but it was my mistake.  I had the Javascript wrapped in a function and didn't call the function.  Completely my mistake.

Comment: feel free to delete the question then :)

Comment: @ochi it wont let me, since people answered.

Comment: Oh, well! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to include your script or forgot to include the source for jquery or angularjs, but this worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="some_button">some button</button>
    <script>
    $('#some_button').click(function(e) {
        alert('testing');
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you post more of the source code? maybe include the relevant html structure and javascript

Comment: nvm i got it, i had the js code wrapped in a function which i didn't call. ill delete the question,thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some_button').click(function(e) { 
      alert('testing');
});
});
</script>
```